# Design patterns for input types with unions

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

Lets say I have an entity that has a type signature like this (using typescript syntax):

```
    type WordDocument = {
        name: string,
        lines: PossibleLineTypes[]
    }
    
    type PossibleLineTypes = { 
        type: 'A', 
        exclusiveToA: string 
    } | {
        type: 'B', 
        exclusiveToB: number
    }
```

Im trying to structure an input type that will allow me to create a parent object in a single mutation which is proving to be tricky.

Option 1 - Use nullable values for any exclusive properties on the child type:

```
    // Graphql types
    type WordDocument {
        name: String!
        lines: [Line!]!
    }
    
    type Line {
        type: PossibleLineTypesEnum!
        exclusiveToA: String // nullable
        exclusiveToB: Number // nullable
    }
```

This is what i’m doing at the moment - its far from ideal because it means I have to manually check the right properties have been defined per type/variant (and the actual type is much larger than my example). Its very annoying because I have input types for the above which I need to transform into service types with the correct pairing of properties which is meaning I cannot share the input types and the service method input types.

Option 2 - Separate the different types into different properties

```
    // Graphql types
    type WordDocument {
        name: String!
        linesA: [LineA!]!,
        linesB: [LineB!]!,
    }
    
    type LineA {
        exclusiveToA: String 
    }
    
    type LineB {
        exclusiveToB: Number 
    }
```

My main issue with this is that I have a very nested document and separating each variant on each layer gets insane but also I lose the ability to keep the order of the lines added to the document without adding an order field to the line types.

Has anyone faced this? struggling to find the preferred pattern for this

Comment: Why don't you create a custom scalar? A custom scalar that describes a `Line` that accepts both a `string` and a `number`. If `Number.parseInt` returns `NaN`, a `string` has been given as input, otherwise, you have a `number`.

Comment: This was just an example - the actual types are not scalars but other objects

Comment: For more information see https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/488 and https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/825

Comment: What am I looking at exactly? oneOf? looks like it hasn't been added to gql yet

Comment: Cannot find any docs on this other than this RFC so don't think this answers the question as it doesn't seem to be implemented - https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/1302, https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#Directive (its not in the spec)

Comment: Yes, there is no such feature in GraphQL (currently)